# How to identify decimal values within strings using regex

Tags: regex

I have the following `SHAKE LQ 1.30 ML (60 MG) PO QD FOR 7 DAYS THEN DR` and trying to only identify `30 ML`.

I have tried the following but capture the `30` in `1.30 ML`.

```
((30|45|60)(\s)?(ML))
```

How can I not capture combination of whole numbers that fall in decimal values.

Comment: `\d+\.(30|45|60)\s+ML` seems to work for your example. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Use `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)(30|45|60)\s?(ML)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to extract `30 ML` from a string like `SHAKE LQ 30 ML (60 MG)` and detect no match in a string like `SHAKE LQ 1.30 ML (90 MG)`.

You may use

```
(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)((30|45|60)\s?(ML))\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyCyzS/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` - no digit and no digit + `.` allowed before the 
  number
- `((30|45|60)\s?(ML))` - Capturing group 1:

  - `(30|45|60)` - Capturing group 2: `30`, `45` or `60`
  - `\s?` - an optional whitespace
  - `(ML)` - Capturing group 3: `ML`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal is:

```
\d+\.\d{2}\s
```

Explanation:

```
\d number
+ one or more preceding character
\. literal dot
{2} exactly two preceding characters
\s white space
```

EDIT.
Non decimal is:

```
[^.]\d{2}\s
```

Example in JavaScript:

```js
s1='SHAKE LQ 30 ML (60 MG) PO QD FOR 7 DAYS THEN DR';
s2='SHAKE LQ 1.30 ML (60 MG) PO QD FOR 7 DAYS THEN DR';
r=/[^.]\d{2}\s+ML/
console.log(r.exec(s1)); //returns 30ML in array
console.log(r.exec(s2));  //returns null
```

Comment: I am trying to capture only whole numbers. If the value comes up in a decimal value it should not match. 30 valid but 1.30 invalid.

Comment: @swvickery You must provide the output you want to get from the input string. Even after your editing, it is unclear what exactly you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\d?\.\d+(*SKIP)(?!)|((30|45|60)\s?(ML))`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4VR1n/1)

If not support pcre

Try `(?<![\d.])((30|45|60)\s?(ML))`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/p18qnQ/1)